# Command Line Argument adding an extra parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to explore command line argument in C++ in Visual Studio 2010. It is working fine but it is adding one extra parameter at args[0] any reason why?

Here is the snapshot of how I am setting my arguments

[image]

the main method is as follows

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout<< endl << "total args passed in the command line - " << argc << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    cout << i+1<< " argument  - " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

The output on cmd is looking like this

[image]

As you can see that I am adding only two arguments but it is showing the count as 3.

Comment: _"enter image description here"_ is an instruction; please follow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first entry in the list is the program name; that's how it's designed to work.

Answer (score 4):

args[0] contains the name of your program and argc includes this in the count aswell.

If you would like to exclude this, try this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout<< endl << "total args passed in the command line - " << argc - 1 << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        cout << i << " argument  - " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```